# Error While Upgrading Magento2.1 to Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2

while upgrading Magento run command composer update error shown :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

***Can you try adding the following to your root composer.json file?***

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://packages.magento.com/"
        }
    ]
```